# Asp.Net Core 2.2 - Understanding Authentication Middleware and External Logins

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-2.2

I have been trying to wrap my head around this concept but have many questions and unfortunately, all official documents and tutorials are based on Visual Studio templates with individual user accounts.

My goal is pretty straightforward I believe. I have a web application which will only support external provider logins (namely: Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn). I do not want to support cookie authentication since there won't be a support for custom username/password.

My first problem is to define a default AuthenticationScheme. Below is my startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddFacebook(/* options */)
        .AddTwitter(/* options */)
```

If I define a controller action with Authorize attribute I get no default authentication scheme defined error when I hit that route. However, I want users to be redirected to my login route if they are unauthorized. If I modify startup.cs like below it all works but then I think I support cookie (old forms authentication?) authentication which I don't want to.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie()
        .AddFacebook(/* options */)
```

My other issue is that I don't know what happens under the hood of AddFacebook() call. If I set up my middleware this way and log in with Facebook I magically get all the necessary tokens, claims and suddenly I have an application cookie set and my fb_login callback route can access to Facebook's token! When I check the network requests I see there is a hit to the signin-facebook route -which I didn't define- and I guess under the hood it calls HttpContext.SignInAsync() etc... but if I refresh my fb-login callback and check if

```
HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

returns Success = true **no!** it returns false! But it was true just one second ago?

Also, when should I be using methods like AuthenticateAsync() and SignInAsync()?

Long story short I **need** a tutorial or documentation that explains this middleware *without* asp.net Identity framework, EntityFramework and templates.

I want to understand how a simple AddFacebook() call binds everything, and if I want to manually do that (say with AddOauth) how can I achieve the same functionality?

I'm not a fan of "automagically working" code so if someone can explain what's going on here I'd be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to implement login with socials manually too but no documentation exists.

Answer (score 2):

Cookie auth is used to persist the authenticated state between the requests. There is no substitute for this, and no it's not the same as forms auth, though cookies are used in both cases. The reason for that is simply that cookies are what makes state work over the HTTP protocol, which is itself stateless. If exclude the use of cookies, then there is no other mechanism to maintain state.

Using something like the Facebook auth scheme directly authorizes the initial request, but again, because there is no state, the next request is no longer authenticated without going through the Facebook OAuth flow again.

Long and short, the other auth schemes are there for things like APIs, where each request is typically authenticated individually via something like the `Authorization` header. A web browser doesn't work this way, and instead relies on cookies handle subsequent authorization. No cookies, no auth.